# Unable to access functional property in Javascript object from a static method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following object in my NodeJS application

**customer.js**

```
const CustomerRepository= require('../repositories/customer');

module.exports = {
    findByApiKey: async (apiKey) => {
        return await CustomerRepository.findByApiKey(apiKey);
    }
};
```

Now I have another file called **consumerservice.js** as follows

```
const CustomerService = require('./customer'); //from the customer.js file above

class ConsumerService{

    static async validateAPIKey(apiKey) {
        let requestingClientData = await CustomerService.findByApiKey(apiKey);
        return requestingClientData;
    }

}
module.exports = ConsumerService;
```

Surprisingly I am getting `findByApiKey` is not a function? This is weird. What could be wrong?

```
(node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findByApiKey' of module exports inside circular dependency
2021-05-17T23:19:26.221263+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: CustomerService.findByApiKey is not a function
2021-05-17T23:19:26.221265+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.validateAPIKey (/app/services/customer.js:9:53)
2021-05-17T23:19:26.221265+00:00 app[web.1]:     at fetchCustomer (/app/services/consumer.js:30:59)
```

Comment: Is the `CustomerRepository.findByApiKey(apiKey)` from inside the `customer.js` file defined? It might be a problem with that function since they have the same name.

Comment: Yea,it is defined. I've edited the question to include that information. Thank you.

Comment: Which module throws the error? And can you share error callstack with us, please?

Comment: Do you realize that the `await` in `return await CustomerRepository.findByApiKey(apiKey);` is pointless.  Just do `return CustomerRepository.findByApiKey(apiKey);`.  Both are just returning a promise that resolves when the asynchronous operation is done.  And, then your function doesn't even need to be `async` either.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for pointing that out. Actually it's not really useless, it's consumed in many places that requires the promises behavior, the consumer service isn't the only caller of the function so removing it will break other areas where it is called.

Comment: @user15155716 - No, you're confused.  Whether the `await` is there or not, you're returning the same promise.  No difference to the caller.  `return await something()` implies you think the function is return the value directly.  It's not.  It's returning a promise that resolves to the value with either `return await something()`  or with `return something()` .  So, the `await` is superfluous.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're losing focus. Your response doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: "*Accessing non-existent property … of module exports inside **circular dependency***" is a pretty clear warning to me. Something is calling `fetchCustomer` while the imports are still resolving, and you have a circular dependency.

Comment: That's why this is a comment.  It's a comment on your code, not a solution - that's one thing we can use comments for.  If I had any ideas for an answer, I'd write an answer.  As it is there is no debugging information at all other than the stack trace.  The #1 troubleshooting thing to do is to add a `console.log(CustomerService)` and see what it's value is.  It apparently is not what you want it to be so go see what it actually is.

Comment: Bergi is right. Some of the dependencies of `customer.js` require this module and at this point it's not ready so there's no `fetchCustomer` method on the module yet. You need to fix your dependencies.

Comment: @Bergi you are the Boss here!!! Your suggestion was so on point. I seriously had circular dependencies in my code  after thorough review. I eventually hoisted my imports and the issue is fixed now. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your input.